# Having trouble creating PDF from Excel using MSAccess and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pdf

I created some code in VBA that opens an Excel file, grabs multiple sheets and then creates a PDF from them. The code works the first time and then fails with a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error the second time.

This is in a loop grabbing a file per record, but I can have it just do one at a time and exit the function. Even then, after closing the function and then starting it up again, it fails.

```
PDFName="The file name.pdf"

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(MDestDir)

Xl.Visible = True

Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(MSumName)

XlBook.Worksheets(Array(MSumName, "Technical Effectiveness", "Project 
Participation-Mngmt", "Personal Effectiveness", "Business Effectiveness", 
"Organizational - Management", "Core Values")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
PDFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

XlBook.Close True

Xl.Quit
```

So... From a menu in the program, I select a user/record and click on a button to run this function. It works fine. Then I click the button again to run it and I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It took my typing this whole thing out that led me to double check code that I had written in the past. I put the workbook object on the ActiveSheet line and it all started working.

```
xl.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
PDFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```